# SQL query case when at least one

Tags: sql

How to use `CASE` to show `'debtor'` if **at least one** of the invoices is not paid (Invoice_Status = 1)?

*(A customer has multiple invoices)

Here's the query to show the an Id_Customer and the status of his multiple invoices, but this repeats the Id_Customer for each invoice he has

```js
SELECT Id_Customer, 
    CASE Invoice_Status
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Debtor'
        ELSE 'No debts'
    END AS Status
FROM Tb_Invoices
ORDER BY Id_Customer
GO
```

Comment: Please include minimal `create table ` and `insert into ` next time, and tag the question with the database you use.  SQL is a generic term.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an aggregate (min, max, count etc) on Invoice_Status, then map that value via you case statement.  You haven't told us about your schema or data so we can't really help you more than that.  I.e. something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN count(Invoice_Status = 1) > 0 THEN 'Dector'
   ELSE 'No debts'
END
FROM Tb_Invoices
ORDER BY Id_Customer
```